# Adding ActionBarSherlock as library to project

Tags: android, android-emulator, intellij-idea, actionbarsherlock

I have a problem with the new ActionBarSherlock.
I have to link it to my project and use it's features (Fragments, etc), in a project that supports android API level 7 and above.

I have created a module in intelij with my project, and I've linked the ActionBarSherlock library project to it. Everything looks good, the project rebuilds correctly, deploy a valid apk to emulator, but when I'm trying to run the application I got something like this:

```
WARN/dalvikvm(540): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mobileinsight/common/CustomActivity; (134)
WARN/dalvikvm(540): Link of class 'Lcom/mobileinsight/common/CustomActivity;' failed
WARN/dalvikvm(540): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/mobileinsight/ui/SplashActivity; (175)
WARN/dalvikvm(540): Link of class 'Lcom/mobileinsight/ui/SplashActivity;' failed
WARN/dalvikvm(540): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)`

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(540): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mobileinsight/com.mobileinsight.ui.SplashActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mobileinsight.ui.SplashActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@45f352e8
```

I get the error when the application tries to instantiate an activity that extends `SherlockActivity` or `FragmentSherlockActivity`

Somebody can help me with this?

Thanks,
Ark

Comment: Did you include v4-support library as well ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to link it for `ActionBarSherlock` library, and it didn't worked, after that I linked it with the project and the library did not work, and finally I linked it to both project and library, and in the end everything compiled correctly, but the problem described showed up

Comment: Did you try to add the `v4-support` library to the library module only and enable the **export** checkbox? If it still doesn't work, please zip and share a complete sample project to reproduce the problem.

Comment: CommonsWare answered my question with the same problems [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466648/adding-actionbarsherlock-library-creates-errors-involving-android-support-v4)

Comment: Thanks JuiCe, please add a link or something as answer so I can accept it.