# Adding ActionBarSherlock library creates errors involving android.support.v4

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

My existing project runs smoothly using Fragments and FragmentPagerAdapters. However, when adding the `ActionBarSherlock` library errors appear. I have found [another question] with the same problems, but there are no answers.

Before adding the library to my project, it looks like this with no errors:

[image]

After adding the library, I edit the `AndroidManifest.xml` to include `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Sherlock"`, which produces an error in my XML file as well. When I change it to `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"`, the error in the XML file disappears but it still doesn't work and the errors look like this:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I have done what was suggested in CommonsWare's answer below, but my code is still not working properly. All errors go away and the project builds and even launches on my device. However when I enter the Graphical layout of my XML files I get the following error:

```
The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
```

This is what the XML file looks like. Note that my XML file shows no errors, but when I enter the `Graphical Layout` tab the above message appears. I had not mentioned that I am using a `ViewPager` but I didn't think it would make a difference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/wavesMonitorMenuBar"
        style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/menu_back" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/readButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/menu_read" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/statusPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/wavesMonitorMenuBar" >
    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#9E9E9E"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp" />


    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</RelativeLayout>
```

From here I went to chose `Fix Build Path` but still couldn't solve the problem. I tried selecting both `library.jar` and `android-support-v4.jar` but to no avail. The program crashes when I try to open any views that use the XML files with these errors.

This is the window I get when I choose `Fix Build Path`:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your console is telling you in red, you have two JARs, named `android-support-v4.jar`, and they are not the same actual file -- their sizes or contents differ. Hence, Android does not know which of the two JARs you want.

Usually, the simple answer is to delete the JAR from your project. ActionBarSherlock has this JAR, and your project will pick that one up as part of having ActionBarSherlock attached as a library project.

Comment: Using your answer got rid of all of my errors and enabled my code to build and launch, but it still does not work. I have edited my question with updates if you have a chance to look at it.

Comment: @JuiCe: The JAR in the ActionBarSherlock project is too old and does not contain `PagerTabStrip`. Download the current Android Support Library from the SDK Manager (if you are not on the current one), then copy its JAR into the `libs/` of the ActionBarSherlock project to replace the one that is there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried running it on the ActionBarSherlock project but it was already there, and it didn't help. I then did it on my main project, and without moving it to the `libs/` directory of the ActionBarSherlock project* the application now works. Will I run into problems later? The `support` jar is in both locations, just like you told me not to do earlier, but it works now.

Comment: @JuiCe: "The support jar is in both locations, just like you told me not to do earlier, but it works now" -- well, it must be the same version of the JAR (otherwise, your original error would have returned), so you should be OK.

Answer (score 2):

The android-support-v4.jar in SherlockActionBar is too old(at least in my downloaded project) and it does not contain PagerTabStrip.

I resolve it by replacing the support library in actionbarsherlock library project.

Answer (score 0):

SherlockActionBar has android-support-v4.jar in his libs folder. Try to remove android-support-v4.jar from your project's lib folder, so that jar will be used from Sherlock's project.